# Code words in integer sequences

Tags: code-golf, number, word

#### Introduction

*Pareidolia*: From Ancient Greek; *παρα* ‎(*para*, “concurrent, alongside”) + *εἴδωλον* ‎(*eídōlon*, “image”). The tendency to interpret a vague stimulus as something known to the observer, such as interpreting marks on Mars as canals, seeing shapes in clouds, or hearing hidden messages in music. Source: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pareidolia).

For example:

[image]

*Paralogia*: From Ancient Greek; *παρα* ‎(*para*, “concurrent, alongside”) + *λόγος* ‎(*lógos*, “speech, oration, word, ...”). The tendency to perceive words in arbitrary sequences of characters, such as in code golf programs. Source: yeah, I made that up (actually the word means [something else](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/paralogia), as pointed out by @Martin).

For example:

```
    df4$/H)hEy_^p2\
    jtK2$)look|x1$
```

#### Challenge

Write a program that takes a positive integer as input, produces an integer as output, and includes an English word as part of the code. The input-output relationship must correspond to an integer sequence that can be found in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

#### Rules

- Only words from this [**list**](http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt) are allowed. This is admittedly arbitrary, but it's essential that we all agree on which words are accepted; and in that regard this list is probably as good as any other.
- Words need to be formed by **concatenating** at least two function names or statements. If your language for example has a function called `correlation` it can't be used as is. The concatenation has to be strict: no other symbols should appear between the parts of the word. For example, `bro~ken` would not count as a word.
- **Case** is unimportant: both `valid` and `vaLiD`are acceptable.
- Words within strings do not count. The letters that make up the word need to be functions or statements in the language of choice, that is, something that is actually **executed**. For example, the following code would not be allowed: `'deoxyribonucleic'~1`, where `'...'` is a string, `~` discards the previous content, and `1` just prints number `1`.
- Every letter of the word should be **necessary**. This means that removing a single letter from the word should change the input-output relation. That includes outputting a different sequence, or outputting any other thing(s), or producing no output, or causing an error.
- Any **positive integer** should be acceptable as an input, and should produce an output, except for data-type or memory restrictions.
- The outputs corresponding to inputs `1`, `2`, `3`, ... should correspond to a sequence appearing in [**OEIS**](https://oeis.org/). No other output should be produced; only an integer number, possibly with trailing or leading whitespace.
- Input and output can be function arguments or stdin/stdout.

#### Score

The score is computed as total code length minus twice the length of the longest word, in characters. Or equivalently, number of not-in-longest-word characters minus length of longest word.

Lowest score wins.

#### Examples

Consider an imaginary postfix language that has these functions: `c`: input a number; `At`: compute square; `$`: add 1.

`cAt` would be a valid program (its output corresponds to the sequence `1`, `4`, `9`, ..., which is [A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290)), and it would have score −3.

`cAt$` would also be valid (sequence `2`, `5`, `10`, ..., which is [A002522](https://oeis.org/A002522)), with score −2.

`c$At` would not be valid, because the only word here is "At" and is produced by a single function or statement.

Comment: I think this should be a popularity contest.

Comment: @MCMastery This would not make a good popularity contest. (Most challenges wouldn't.)

Comment: This is essentially limited to golfing languages though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## CJam, -20

```
COUNTErREVOLUTIONARIES],
```

Outputs the nth element in the sequence [A010861](https://oeis.org/A010861).

```
COUNTE                      e# push values of six preinitialized variables
      r                     e# read a token of input
       REVOLUTIONARIES      e# push values of 15 other preinitialized variables
                      ]     e# wrap whole stack in array
                       ,    e# get length
```

Removing a character from the word results in a completely different sequence [A010860](https://oeis.org/A010860). There is a quite interesting relationship between the two sequences: at every index n, `A010860(n)` is coprime to `A010861(n)`! There must be some deep mathematical reason behind this.

Try it [here](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=Q09VTlRFclJFVk9MVVRJT05BUklFU10s&input=&args=MjM0NTE).

Comment: I have discovered another curious mathematical relationship: if you subtract the A010860 sequence from the A010861 sequence, the result always equals 1 at every index! Fascinating...

Comment: This one's going to be hard to beat :-)

Comment: Oh, upper case..  Great idea :)

Answer (score 10):

### CJam, -5

```
limpet;
```

[A010051](https://oeis.org/A010051): prints `0` for composite numbers and `1` for primes.

It took me forever to find something that scored a few points and would break at the removal of any letter. Removing anything except `m` throws an error, and removing `m` turns the program into the identity function.

```
li  e# Read input and convert to integer.
mp  e# Check for primality.
et  e# Get current datetime as a list.
;   e# Discard the datetime again.
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=limpet%3B&input=9)

Comment: Beautiful choice of sequence! :-)

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>-4</s> -11

Code, prints [A010869](https://oeis.org/A010869) (constant 30):

```
ASYNcHRonouSlyI)g
```

---

Previous code:

```
DoGS
```

Explanation:

```
D     # Duplicate top of the stack
 o    # Pop a, push 2**a
  G   # For N in range(1, 2**a):
   S  # Push all chars seperate from the top of the stack
```

Prints the [A010879](https://oeis.org/A010879) sequence.

Comment: That's the most interesting sequence so far!

Comment: Crossed out -4 is still regular -4 ;(

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), −6

```
INhale
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=SU5oYWxl&input=NQ)

Produces sequence `1`, `2`, `3`, ... ([A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027))

Removing any letter changes the output, or leaves the program expecting a second input which doesn't exist, or produces an error.

#### Explanation

The program simply *inhales* a number and, after some fiddling around, exhales it unchanged.

```
I    % produces number 3
N    % number of elements in stack: produces number 1
h    % concatenates horizontally into array [3, 1]
a    % true if any element is nonzero. So it gives true (or equivalently 1)
l    % produces number 1
e    % triggers implicit input and reshapes into a 1x1 array. So it leaves input unchanged
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 1

```
*QhSatan0000
   Satan
```

Explanation?

```
       n00   - 0 != 0 (0) 
      a   0  - abs(^-0) (0, Required so it doesn't print out a random 0)
     t       - ^-1 (-1, required or will output 0 all the time)
    a      0 - abs(^-0) (1, Required so counts in right direction, would also print out a random 0)
   S         - 1-indexed range ([1], required so next command works properly)
  h          - Get the head (if `S` missed, will out 2)
*Q           - Multiply by Q
```

1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

[Sequence A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027)

Subliminal messages? Never.

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*QhSatan0000&input=3&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, -6

```
NuLLIFIED)r^
```

Outputs [A004453](http://oeis.org/A004453): nimsum of N and 12  (N XOR 12). [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=TnVMTElGSUVEKXJe&input=MQ==)

Note: the OEIS sequence is 0-indexed, so an input of 0 will result in the first item.

#### How it works

```
        // Implicit: N = array of inputs
Nu      // Push the following things to N:
LLIF    // 100, 100, 64, 15,
IED     // 64 again, 14, and 13.
)r^     // Reduce by XORing (using ^ between each pair)
        // The reduction goes as follows: U, U^100, U, U^64, U^79, U^15, U^1, U^12.
```

Comment: Nice! Any explanation, when you can?

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure, done. It's incredibly simple, but I haven't found anything more complex yet.

Comment: @LuisMendo Updated. This one's a little more interesting.

Comment: Indeed! But apparently removing the `Y` produces the same output? (unless I'm doing something wrong)

Comment: @Luis Is this better?

Comment: Yes indeed it is!

Answer (score 3):

## [Headsecks](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headsecks), score −4

```
exit
```

This maps to the Brainfuck program `,+-.`, which reads a single character and prints it, calculating [A000030](https://oeis.org/A000030). Removing any character will obviously break it.

There's also `marshal` (`,-<>+-.`), which is effectively `,-.`, but that doesn't correspond to any OEIS sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code, score -4

Hexdump of the code:

```
53 51 55 41 53 68 69 65 73 74 51 58 83 c4 14 c3
```

Or, in [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437):

```
SQUAShiestQXâ─¶├
```

Assembly code:

```
push ebx
push ecx
push ebp
inc ecx
push ebx
push 0x74736569
push ecx
pop eax
add esp, 0x14
ret
```

A function that [adds 1 to its argument](https://oeis.org/A020725).

Removing `A` turns it into an identity function. Removing any other byte messes up the stack, causing either a crash or bad behavior of the calling function.

I am pretty sure it's possible to improve the score, but it may depend on the interpretation of the requirements. For example, using the word `SQUEAMIShness` gives a program, that increases and then decreases the `ebp` register. Does removing any of these cause a crash? A simplest test program doesn't use the `ebp` register, so maybe it doesn't... To avoid this doubt, I used a shorter word.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, score 3

```
puts gets.partition''
```

This computes the [identity sequence A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027). Output is surrounded by some whitespace; I hope that's okay.

Comment: Yes, whitespace is fine

Answer (score 1):

## Math++, score -2

```
?*sine
```

Implements [A000004](https://oeis.org/A000004).